# For items in a dictonary, split the name of one item, add and remove some info python

Tags: python

I have a dictionary with this info:

```
x = {Country:{City:Population},.....}
```

but City name is now like: `Country_City_Neighbourhood_Population` (for some reason). I need to remove all the information and just keep the City and Neighbourhood like this: `CityNeighbourhood`.

I did this:

```
for country in x:
 for city, pop in x[country].iteritems():
  isCountry = city.split("_").count("Ecuador")
  if isCountry > 0:
   city1 = city.split("_")
   city1.remove("Ecuador")
   city2 = city1[0:-1]
   city3 = ""
   for i in range(len(city2)-1):
    city3 = city3 + city2[i]
```

but I didn't obtain any reasonable result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
for country in x:
    for city, pop in x[country].iteritems():
        if 'Ecuador' in city:
            print ''.join(city.split('_')[1:3])
```

Comment: neatness: iterate over `x.items()` to and remove the `x[country]` lookup

Answer (score 4):

```
"".join(city.split("_")[1:-1])
```

- `city.split("_")` gives a list of the words in "city" separated by "_".
- `[1:-1]` [slices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation/509295#509295) the list to remove the first and last elements
- `"".join` connects them back together, with the empty string in between

Comment: thanks!!! but you mean that I have to do this:
city3 = "".join(city.split("_")[1:-1])  ????

Comment: @Alejandro: if you want... you can do whatever you like with the result of the call. Maybe you want `for country in x: x[country] = "".join(x[country].split("_")[1:-1])`?